# How to retrieve a value in a dataframe and use it as variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, variables

I have some values stored in a dataframe and I would like to take them and use them as variable names. How do I do that without writing/Hardcode the variable name?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately your question does not follow the standard of a questions here. I know that you've put data in another question, but each question should have data, code, expected result, and your lacks of those things. It does not seems an hard issue, but to me, your question is unclear, and it risks to be close without any useful answer. Please add the features mentioned, and you'll increase the chance to get a good answer.

Comment: see `?assign()`

Comment: @MikkoMarttila If use as example the code from Joseph's comment. which is: `data <- data.frame("Name"=c("John", "Evie", "Graham", "Mary"), 
                   "Age"=c(13,43,26,17), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

people <- list()

for(row in 1:nrow(data)){

    people[[data[row, "Name"]]] <- data[row, "Age"]
}` will the function `assign()` allow me to do something like `for (i in nrow(data)) { data$Name[i] <- "X" }` where R will create new variables with the names in the list without having to write the following: `John <- "X" Graham <- "X" Mary <- "X"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `assign()` function. Here is an example:

```
data <- data.frame("Name"=c("John", "Evie", "Graham", "Mary"), 
                   "Age"=c(13,43,26,17), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(row in 1:nrow(data)){

    assign(x=data[row, "Name"], value=data[row, "Age"])
}

print(Evie)
```

$Evie

[1] 43

Comment: Thanks for your answer can I now do something like `for (i in nrow(data)) {
  data$Name[i] <- "X"
}
` where R will create new variables with the names in the list without having to write the following: `John <- "X"
Graham <- "X"
Mary <- "X"`

Comment: See the edit. As @MikkoMarttila, you can use the `assign()` function